# Spring integration ServiceActivator autostartup flag

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream

I have a Spring Boot app with ServiceActivator annotated method for reading Message objects from a queue. Something like:

```java
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
public class MyProcessor {
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = Sink.INPUT)
    public void process(final Message<?> message) {
       // ...
    }
}
```

However, now I have a requirement to load a user script and use it to preprocess the messages' payloads. This load may fail or the script might not compile. If this happens, I want to not start up my sink and just leave the messages sitting on the queue until the problem is fixed and the app restarted.

ServiceActivator has an autostartup attribute, so it seems like I could set that to false, and then start the sink manually when I'm satisfied that the script is OK. However, I can't figure out how or when to do that manual start.

Answer (score 0):

It is more a Spring Cloud Stream concern. That's why I added a respective tag into your question.

So, before you reach a good condition for your script, you really must not start to consume from the messaging middleware. For this reason the `@ServiceActivator` is already too late. The consuming from the queue would already be started.

My point is really do not have that *binding* to be started. You can do that with a binding consumer property: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/2.2.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-stream.html#_consumer_properties

> **autoStartup**
>
> Signals if this consumer needs to be started automatically
>
> Default: `true`.

You can then handle it's start later via `Binding.start()`.

Comment: I'm not having a lot of luck with this. I set: "spring.cloud.stream.input.consumer.autoStartup=false" in my application.yml. (I also tried "spring.cloud.stream.default.consumer.autoStartup=false", because I wasn't clear which was right.) Neither had any apparent effect. The process() method still triggered and processed the message as usual. Setting the annotation @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = Sink.INPUT, autoStartup = "false") stopped the process() method from running, but instead I got an error: "Dispatcher has no subscribers". The message was still removed from the input queue.